# How to find correspondent basis of a matrix associated to a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let's say I have a linear transformation $f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ defined as: $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x_1+x_2-x_3, \ 2x_1 - 3x_2 + 2x_3, \ 3x_1-2x_2 + x_3) $.

How can I find $\beta_1, \beta_2$ such that $[f]_{\beta_1\beta_2} = \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$ is the matrix associated to $f$ in the bases $\beta_1, \beta_2$?

I was thinking that if $\beta_1 = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ then $f(v1)_{\beta_2} = (1,0,0)$ and so on, but I don't know how to actually find such bases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&-1\\ \:2&-3&2\\ \:3&-2&1\end{pmatrix}$ be the standard matrix of $f$. The reduced row echelon form of $A$ is $\text{rref}(A)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-\frac{1}{5}\\ 0&1&-\frac{4}{5}\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$. From elementary linear algebra we know $\text{rref}(A)=RA$ where $R$ is a product of elementary matrices that encode the elementary row operations we use to transform $A$ into $\text{rref}(A)$.

If we apply the elementary *column* operations $C_1\cdot \frac{1}{5}+C_3 \iff C_3$ and $C_2\cdot \frac{4}{5}+C_3 \iff C_3$ on $I_{3\times 3}$ we obtain the matrix $C$ given by $$C=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\frac{1}{5}\\ 0&1&\frac{4}{5}\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ Multiplying the above matrix *on the left* by $\text{rref}(A)$ puts your matrix in the desired form. In other words, $$RAC=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ Taking $\beta_1=\{Ce_1,Ce_2,Ce_3\}$ and $\beta_2=\{R^{-1}e_1,R^{-1}e_2,R^{-1}e_3\}$ should do the trick.